# How do I prove $\frac{ \sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x} }{ h}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

$$\frac{ \sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x} }{ h}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}$$

I know I just asked a question and I did figure out how that one worked but I'm not sure how I would go about this one.

Comment: as already answered you should multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}$, this process is usually called rationalization and it's based on some common identities, such as $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, as in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{(x+h)-x} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}
\end{align}

Comment: That made it much clearer to me.

Comment: I'd have mentioned that this is called rationalizing the numerator.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:**
Multiply by
$$
1 = \frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Multiply the top and bottom by $\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}&=\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}} \\
&=\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}\end{align}$$ by multiplying by $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Just like DanZimm said, multiply by numerator conjugate:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}h \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x} = \frac{(x+h)-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)} = \frac 1{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}$$

[image]